# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long in a for loop

Tags: python, windows, cython

I am using cython to loop over large numbers and here is what I have in my `test.pyx`:

```
cpdef int counter(int n):
    cdef int count= 0
    cdef int i
    for i in range(n):
        count += i*2
    return count
```

running

```
>>> counter(10000000000)
```

gives the following error:

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

I am not using numpy or any other library, just a simple `for` loop. is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Use a double instead of a long?

Comment: Please, can you explain you answer

Comment: You can't store 10^9 in a C long. There is nothing you can do about that. There is a hardware limit, which is 2^31-1. But if you don't actually need your value to be an integer, you could use floating-point arithmetic instead. That can handle the magnitude you want, at the possible sacrifice of some precision.

Comment: thank you @BoarGules, I have not gone into it yet, but, do you think that using [cython Parallelism](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html) could help?

Comment: No, I can't honestly see any way that would help. The Cython docs recommend that if you want to use numeric Python types like `int` instead of their C counterparts, simply omit the type declaration and let them be objects.

Comment: You might be able to use `long long` instead of `int`. Maybe.

Comment: thank you @DavidW, using `long long` did work!

Comment: Assuming both `i` and `n` are positive values, you could also try `unsigned long long` so that you essentially "double" the range of positive integers that can be represented.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: yes you can fix it, use c type "long long", not c type "int".

Long answer and explanation of the error:

Your parameter in cython is a c int (not to be confused with a python 2 int or a python 3 int which are different things), which has a limited range. Assuming a modern desktop/server os it's range will almost certainly be −2147483648 to 2147483647 . So clearly 10000000000 will not fit. We have an error here, but why does the error message mention "long" when you are using type int? lets try and look at the code.

Looking at the cython generated source this conversion. is handled by a function "__Pyx_PyInt_As_int". This function was clearly created by substituting the C type name into a text template, with the result it contains a fair bit of dead code. Lets work though it.

```
static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_PyInt_As_int(PyObject *x) {
   const int neg_one = (int) -1, const_zero = (int) 0;
   const int is_unsigned = neg_one > const_zero;
```

This first chunk of code figures out whether the C type the function is working with is unsigned or not.

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
     <----- snip---->
#endif
```

This chunk of code is not relavent to us, it only has an effect when the python object is a python 2.x int (not to be confused with a C int or a python 3.x int).

```
    if (likely(PyLong_Check(x))) {
```

Now we are getting somewhere, this is the case that handles python2 longs and python3 ints

```
        if (is_unsigned) {
            <---snip a massive chunk of dead code---> 
        } else {
#if CYTHON_USE_PYLONG_INTERNALS
             <--snip a bunch of optimisations for easy cases-->
#endif
        if (sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)) {
            __PYX_VERIFY_RETURN_INT_EXC(int, long, PyLong_AsLong(x))
```

And finally we get to the explanation for your error message. If the "easy case" code can't handle the value then it is first converted from a python3 int/python2 long to a C long. Then the C long is converted to a C int. So on a platform with 32-bit long the conversion fails at trying to convert 10000000000 to a long, before it tries converting it to an int.